# Applying Where after Group By WorkAround?

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

Is there any way to work around the problem of not being able to use a where clause after the group by statement? Suppose I needed to have the group by, and I wanted to say `WHERE x LIKE 'y'` Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: If you want to filter expressions from group by list you might put your filter in HAVING clause. If not, why can't you use where?

Comment: Please show your sample data, the query you've tried, how the results are wrong, and what results you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter expressions from group by list you might put your filter in HAVING clause.

```
select first, second, third, sum(something) something_summed
from tablea
group by first, second, third
having first + second < 10
```

Comment: Yes. But why you need to put it after group by?

Comment: Use [having](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) to further filter results of any aggregate function whether you used it in select list or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c1,c2,c4
From (
    Select c1,c2,sum(c3) as c4
    From table1
    Group by c1, c2
     ) A
Where A.c1 Like 'yyy'
```

Comment: Why not use `having`? This is less efficient